# How to write the following dictionary in a csv since is failing due to a wrong character map?

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello I have the following object called y_pred

```
listComments = clean.comments
y_pred = kmeans.predict(tfidf)
```

to show the structure of this list and object:

```
print("list of comments",listComments[:10])
print("list of clusters",y_pred[:10])
```

output:

```
list of comments ['hello This', 'Fabiola hello', 'I am using',  ...
list of clusters [ 2 11  2  2 11  2  2  2  2  2]
```

this two sctructures has the same lenght

```
print("length list comments",len(listComments))
print("length list clusters",len(y_pred))
```

output:

```
length list comments 17223
length list clusters 17223
```

then I builded the following dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict
pairs = zip(y_pred, listComments)

dict_clusters2 = defaultdict(list)

for num, comment in pairs:
    dict_clusters2[num].append(comment)
```

to show the sctructure if I perform:

```
for k,v in dict_clusters2.items():
    print(k, v)
```

I got:

```
1 ['hello this is','the car is red',....'performing test']
2 ['we already have','another comment',...'strings strings']
.
.
19 ['we have',' comment music',...'strings strings dance']
My dictionary has a key and a list of several comments I would like to have a csv as follows:

1,'hello this is','the car is red',....'performing test'
2,'we already have','another comment',...'strings strings'

.
.
19,'we have',' comment music',...'strings strings dance'
```

I would like to get a csv file from my dictionary as follows:

```
1,'hello this is','the car is red',....'performing test'
2,'we already have','another comment',...'strings strings'
.
.
19,'we have',' comment music',...'strings strings dance'
```

I tried:

```
with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    for k,v in dict_clusters2.items():
        writer.writerow([k,v])
```

but I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/CleanFile.py", line 217, in <module>
    writer.writerow([k,v])
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f600' in position 294: character maps to <undefined>
```

due to this character mapping that is a emoticon '' '\U0001f600' how can I overcome this situation thanks for the support, 
My version system is the following:

```
3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
3.5.2
```

I tried:

```
with open('dicti','wb') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    for k,v in dict_clusters2.items():
        try:
            print(k)
            print(v[:10])
            writer.writerow([k,v])
        except:
            pass

f.close()
```

Since it is only one character but I got a empty file as a result I hope someone could give me supoort with this.

Comment: Try `with open('test.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as f:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on @juanpa’s suggestion:

```
with open('dicti', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    for k, v in dict_clusters2.items():
        try:
            row = [ k ] + v[:10]
            writer.writerow(row)
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Not handling *any* exception is a bad idea. Also I think we want to include all items, not just the last 10:

```
with open('dictionary.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    for k, v in dict_clusters2.items():
        row = [ k, v]
        writer.writerow(row)
```